# Jira JQL: how to find the busiest hours of a certain queue?

Tags: jira, jql

Jira Server v7.12.1#712002

We have noticed that at certain periods of the day there are more tickets assigned to "Operations" queue than usual, so we need to back this impression with real statistics.

We extracted all the tickets that at some point were assigned to "Operations" queue via the following query:

```
project = "Client Services" AND assignee WAS "Operations"
```

The results of the query above include the timestamp value in the "Updated" field, however this field reflects the last time the ticket was updated - not that we want. We want a timestamp which shows when the ticket arrived to "Operations" queue.

The tickets can arrive in two ways:

1) Ticket may come from other teams. In such cases, under History tab we can observe how 3 different fields change their values. For example, if ticket comes from certain Joe Smith, it would look like this:

```
FIELD                                   ORIGINAL VALUE                           NEW VALUE

Joe Smith made changes - 09/04/2020 12:08

Assignee                                   Joe Smith                             Operations
```

2) Ticket may be created directly (by other teams). In such cases the first 2 entries under History tab always have this pattern:

```
Joe Smith created issue - 02/04/2020 19:27
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
Joe Smith made changes - 02/04/2020 19:27
FIELD                                     ORIGINAL VALUE                           NEW VALUE

Link                                                                        Referred from ABC-12345
```

The pattern above is that `created issue` and `made changes` always have the identical timestamps.

Based on these examples, is there some way to extract the timestamps of all tickets' arrival to "Operations" queue? If not with JQL, maybe some other solution/tool exists?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jira JQL: how to find the busiest hours of a queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370751/jira-jql-how-to-find-the-busiest-hours-of-a-queue)

Comment: @amuratova you pasted a link to my original question